# Apache: Install Baikal besides Seafile

Tags: apache, virtualhost, seafile-server

I need a hint in which direction I should look for an answer on this.

I have set up a Seafile server which is accessible under https://subdomain.no-ip.org, i now want baikal to be accessible under https://subdomain.no-ip.org/baikal

However, I can't get it running because i always get a message from Seafile that this directory does not exist. (I guess seafile thinks it should be a subdirectory)

my recent try to configure apache - 
**sites-enabled/default-ssl**

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    Servername gasslnet.no-ip.org
    DocumentRoot /var/www
    Alias /media /home/andie/seafile-directory/seafile-server-latest/seahub$
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory "/var/www/baikal/html">
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

My Seafile-Settings:

**ccnet/ccnet.conf**

```
SERVICE_URL = https://subdomain.no-ip.org
```

**seahub_settings.py**

```
FILE_SERVER_ROOT = 'http://subdomain.no-ip.org/seafhttp'
```

I think the issue is in the seafile configuration, if seafile would be accessible under url/seafile and not only the url the problem should be solved. I tried changing the SERVICE_URL, but no effect.

Do you have any ideas about this?

Comment: I managed this by assigning different Ports to each Service
Seafile:  https://www.my-server.com:123
Baikal: https://www.my-server.com:234

Answer (score 0):

You have to set

```
SITE_ROOT = '/seafile'
```

in the seahub_settings.py to access Seafile under

```
http://subdomain.no-ip.org/seafile
```